# How do I return a worker back to the worker pool in Go

Tags: multithreading, go

I am implementing a worker pool which can take jobs from a channel. After it kept timing out, I realised that when a panic occurs within a worker fcn, even though I have implemented a recovery mechanism, the worker still does not return to the pool again.

In the golang playground, I was able to replicate the issue:

[Worker Pool Reference](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools)

Modified code for play ground:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "log"

func recovery(id int, results chan<- int) {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        log.Print("IN RECOVERY FUNC - Failed worker: ",id)  
        results <- 0
    }
}

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for j := range jobs {
    defer recovery(id, results)
    if id == 1 {
        panic("TEST")
    }
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "started job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished job", j)
        results <- j * 2
    }
}

func main() {
    jobs := make(chan int, 100)
    results := make(chan int, 100)
    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }
    for j := 1; j <= 10; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)
    for a := 1; a <= 10; a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

For testing, I have implemented a panic when worker 1 is used. When run, the func panics as expected, and goes into recovery as expected (does not push a value into the channel either), however worker 1 never seems to come back.

Output without panic:

```
worker 3 started job 1
worker 1 started job 2
worker 2 started job 3
worker 1 finished job 2
worker 1 started job 4
worker 3 finished job 1
worker 3 started job 5
worker 2 finished job 3
worker 2 started job 6
worker 3 finished job 5
worker 3 started job 7
worker 1 finished job 4
worker 1 started job 8
worker 2 finished job 6
worker 2 started job 9
worker 1 finished job 8
worker 1 started job 10
worker 3 finished job 7
worker 2 finished job 9
worker 1 finished job 10
```

Output with panic:

```
worker 3 started job 1
2009/11/10 23:00:00 RECOVERY Failed worker: 1
worker 2 started job 3
worker 2 finished job 3
worker 2 started job 4
worker 3 finished job 1
worker 3 started job 5
worker 3 finished job 5
worker 3 started job 6
worker 2 finished job 4
worker 2 started job 7
worker 2 finished job 7
worker 2 started job 8
worker 3 finished job 6
worker 3 started job 9
worker 3 finished job 9
worker 3 started job 10
worker 2 finished job 8
worker 3 finished job 10
```

How do I return worker 1 back to the pool after recovery (or in the recovery process)

Comment: are you sure it is recovered properly? the output states: RECOVERY Failed

Comment: That's just my log prints in the code. Let me modify that

Comment: @user2883071 Hi! I think that is because when you panic inside a function it will leave that function. The `recover()` don't prevent your function from crashing. It recover the "thing" used to be panicked, in your case the string "TEST". That is why it `r != nil`.  Here you can find more information about it https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover.

Comment: You don't "return" a worker to the pool, because this pattern doesn't remove them from the pool. They just consume values and operate on them. If you want your worker to continue "working", don't have it return.

Comment: @user2883071 another thing, `defer` is executed when the execution exits the function. So `defer` inside of a loop is a bad smell.

Comment: @JamilloSantos @jimB so if shouldn't return, and I shouldn't panic, how do I ensure the worker keeps working (on other inputs from the channel) if it encounters an error for the current input? (I tried taking out the `panics` and instead push something to the channel and have a blank `return`, but that kills the worker too)

Comment: You could have an `errors` channel passed into the worker functions, and if they encounter an error, send it down the channel and then `continue`. Or, if you don't care about the error, simply `continue` to skip that `job`.

Comment: if I add a `continue` in my `if err != nil` instead of a panic, will it pass by the error only, or escape from the function itself (and work on the other jobs in the queue. I guess my question is what level of escape does continue provide? (error `if` statement level or function level) - Testing it right now

Comment: @TravisHegner It seems like the continue passes the job and moves to the next (from my limited testing). This seems to be a good enough fix, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about the errors, you could have an `errors` channel passed into the worker functions, and if they encounter an `error`, send it down the channel and then `continue`. The main loop could process those errors.

Or, if you don't care about the error, simply `continue` to skip that job.

The [`continue`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Continue_statements) statement basically stops processing that iteration of the loop, and *continues* with the next.